# Read line by line odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How can I print using the new api line by line in myrecord_ids field(name)

```
@api.multi
def func(self):
    for line in self.browse(myrecord_ids):
        print(line.name)
```

I want print this line: https://postimg.org/image/nvl45fuuh/

Comment: Are you getting an error? Where is myrecord_ids defined? It is possible you mean `self.myrecord_ids`

Comment: @phillipstack when use self.myrecord_ids print return: myrecord_ids(1,)
myrecord_ids(2,)
myrecord_ids(3,) how display name

Comment: I will post a solution.

Comment: Does the below modification work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@api.multi
def func(self):
    for line in self.myrecord_ids:
        print(line.name)
```

If you encounter unexpected output you can print all values of your related field by doing the following.

```
@api.multi
def func(self):
    for line in self.myrecord_ids:
        print(line.read([]))
```

Comment: Could you show more of the error you are encountering please/

Comment: It is difficult to guess without knowing more about your code. I will ammend my posting.

Comment: I think what I posted above is what you are looking for.

Comment: Above example return False
False
False

Comment: What other fields do you have available on your related record? From what I can tell you have 3 records on your record `self`. My guess is that the `name` field is not defined on those records. I will amend with a method that will print out all the values of the related record.

Comment: This should print out all the fields and values for your 3 subrecords which will tell you what is going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127294/discussion-between-phillipstack-and-user-odoo).

Comment: I have updated it. Please mark it correct for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if self.myrecord_ids returns myrecord_ids(1,) myrecord_ids(2,) myrecord_ids(3,) then you are working with a recordset, so you can use list comprehension to get all names:

`list_of_names = [i.name for i in self.myrecord_ids]`

and then simply print it in loop or with ', '.join(list_of_names).
In case you want to see IDs, put it in expression, for example:

`list_with_ids = ["%d: %s" % (i.id, i.name) for i in self.myrecord_ids]`